# After and on 2020/03/30 is it correct for writing grammatically?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, formality, writing

Is there any difference "please use this template after 2020/03/30" between "please use this template as of 2020/03/30". Actually, I want to say "please use this template on and after 2020/03/30" Is it correct?

Comment: To clear up confusion I’d write: “beginning March 30, 2020”

Comment: For a compromise between American and European date orders, you might format the date as 30-Mar-2020. Year first works in file names, not in other dates.

Answer (score 1):

To clear up any ambiguity, I would use this construction:

Beginning 2020/03/30, please use this template.

Answer (score 0):

"Please use this template after 2020/03/30" = Do not use this template until 2020/03/**31**

"Please use this template as of 2020/03/30" = Start to use this template on 2020/03/**30**

As has been pointed out, your date format is strange (It is used mainly in Sweden and, as Yosef Baskin says, in file names.)

Comment: It is also the order used by the international standard for interchange of date and time data, ISO 8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the date format in theory, but unless the audience are computing professionals (or are handling tabular data), I would use *Mon, 30-Mar-2020* when writing in natural language. Including both the weekday and yearmonth as text, greatly improves readability, memorability, and compliance. Most people also naturally interpret "starting on" and "finishing on" as being inclusive of the day stated - for example, "the workweek starts on Monday and finishes on Friday".

Comment: To me, as an American professional, DD-mmm-YYYY is as strange and unnatural as YYYY/MM/DD. In ordinary business use in the U.S., we would use ONLY "MM/DD" (3/30), "MM/DD/YYYY" (3/30/2020), "mmm DD" (Mar 30), or "mmm DD, YYYY" (Mar 30, 2020). Any format which puts the date before the month will seem strange and foreign to Americans. From my American perspective, YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-mmm-DD is superior for business use than DD-mmm-YYYY because it retains the month-before-date order of all the other date formats used in the U.S (as well as how dates are spoken here). [MM=numbers, mmm=letters)